# How to Extract Month Name and Year from Date column of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following DF

```
45    2018-01-01
73    2018-02-08
74    2018-02-08
75    2018-02-08
76    2018-02-08
```

I want to extract the month name and year in a simple way in the following format:

```
45    Jan-2018
73    Feb-2018
74    Feb-2018
75    Feb-2018
76    Feb-2018
```

I have used the `df.Date.dt.to_period("M")` which return `"2018-01"` format.

Comment: So you want to convert the top df format to the bottom df?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cast you date from object to actual datetime and use dt to access what you need.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2019-01-01','2019-02-08']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# You can format your date as you wish
df['Mon_Year'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b-%Y')

# the result is object/string unlike `.dt.to_period('M')` that retains datetime data type.

print(df['Mon_Year'])
```

### Visual Format without affecting data types

We could also work with style to get the visual in the way we want without messing with underlying types

```py
# note: returns a style object not df
df.style.format({"Date": lambda t: t.strftime("%b-%Y")})
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `dt` before year and the column?

Comment: I believe you do. After casting `df['Date`].dt.year` shows year. You have all datetime functions as month, day, week number etc from dt

Comment: I am getting the value i wanted. However, since its returning string value, sorting the Date [for plotting and other use] has become an issue.

Comment: Yes, that is why `.dt.to_period` is used. What tools are you using to plot?

Comment: i am using "seaborn"

Comment: Try: `df.set_index('Date')` and the plot whatever columns with `df['My_Numeric_Col'].plot(linewidth=0.5)` see https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-time-series-analysis-with-pandas/

Answer (score 6):

First convert the column to datetime datatype using

```
sales_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(sales_df['Date'])
```

then you can do

```
sales_df['Month'] = sales_df['Date'].dt.month_name(locale='English')
```

Comment: Please, formatting your code to improve legibility. (Using Ctrl. + K)