# Python: Rearranging Dates in a specific column in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel sheet where column F is a list of dates. Currently the structure is as following:

```
Year-Month-Day Hours:Mins:Secs

 - 2014-02-10 10:57:11
 - 2014-07-11 17:43:07
 - .... ect
```

I would like it to be:

```
Month Date Year

 - Feb 11 2014
 - Jul 11 2014
 - .... ect
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Load the excel file -> edit only column F -> Save and replace column F with the new column.

Answer (score 1):

## use `dt.strftime`

```
#first cast column to pandas datetime.
#df['ColumnF'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ColumnF'])
df['ColumnG'] = df['ColumnF'].dt.strftime('%b %d %Y')

              ColumnF      ColumnG
0 2014-02-10 10:57:11  Feb 10 2014
1 2014-07-11 17:43:07  Jul 11 2014
```

### Explanation.

`%b` : Month as locale’s abbreviated name.

`%d` : Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.

`%Y` : Year with century as a decimal number.

Answer (score 0):

```
import calendar 
import pandas as pd

ds = pd.read_excel("date.xlsx")# reads the data 
ds["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(ds["colF"]) # converts datatype of column to datetime64[ns]
ds['Date1'] = ds['Date'].dt.strftime("%B-%d-%Y") # converts months to month name 

#if you want to replace with colF then 
ds['colF']= ds['Date1']
```

There are similar links which you can follow
[python/pandas: convert month int to month name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625334/python-pandas-convert-month-int-to-month-name)

[How to Extract Month Name and Year from Date column of DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57033657/how-to-extract-month-name-and-year-from-date-column-of-dataframe)

Comment: When i print Date1 it shows what i want but it does not save and replace the old ColF?

Comment: @ShawnAtlas Date1 is the new column in the format of required output if you want to replace old colF , you directly use ds['colF'] = ds['Date'].dt.strftime("%B-%d-%Y").